# I wrote a plugin for image slider

Tags: wordpress

I am creating jquery slide show plugin..
i created folder game inside wp-content/plugin

in my folder i have 
readme.txt
game.php
game.css
game.js

In my game.php
i have code:-

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name:game
  Plugin URI: http://URI_Of_Page_Describing_Plugin_and_Updates
  Description: A brief description of the Plugin.
  Version: The Plugin's Version Number, e.g.: 1.0
  Author: Neeraj swarnkar
  Author URI: http://URI_Of_The_Plugin_Author
  License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
 */

/*  Copyright YEAR  PLUGIN_AUTHOR_NAME  (email : neerajswarnkar0207@gmail.com)

  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License, version 2, as
  published by the Free Software Foundation.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 */

function image() {
    hello_world_html_page();
}

add_shortcode('img', 'image');

function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script(
            'game', 'http://localhost/guest1/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/game/game.js'/* don't hardcode your path */, array('jquery')/* this script depends on jquery, so enqueue it automatically */
    );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');

function hello_world_html_page() {
    ?>
    <?php
    return '<div id="demo-top-bar">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div><img alt="TITLE" src="img0.jpg"></div>
            <div><img alt="TITLE"src="img1.jpg"></div>
            <div><img alt="TITLE"src="img2.jpg"></div>
            <div><img alt="TITLE"src="img3.jpg"></div>
            <div>
                Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
            </div>
        </div>';
}
?>
```

In my game.js i have:-

```
$(function() {

    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
        $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);

});
```

In game.css

```
    #slideshow { 
        margin: 80px auto; 
        position: relative; 
        width: 701px; 
        height: 321px; 
        padding: 10px; 
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    }

    #slideshow > div { 
        position: absolute; 
        top: 10px; 
        left: 10px; 
        right: 10px; 
        bottom: 10px; 
    }
```

When i activate and run my progam.. it is showing content of js and css file.. help me i am new on wordpress..

I have updated my changes..

Comment: use - wp_enqueue_script() & wp_register_script() for css and js files

Comment: wp_register_style(), wp_enqueue_style() --> For CSS && wp_register_script(), wp_enqueue_script() --> For JS Follow these link references -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script like same for css

Comment: @swapnesh see my updated code.. now nothing is coming.. i checked on page source script is comoing fine

Comment: For SEO and usability add an alt attribute to your images. http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img/alt

Comment: @swapnesh thanks, i followed the steps which is guide by you... but it is showing nothing..

Comment: @Learner I think janw described what you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First the JS**
You include 2 js, your own and jquery. you haven't registered your won script you just enqueued it.
You can enqueue *and* register it at once. further more I suggest you merge your que:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'game',
        'path/to/your/js'/*don't hardcode your path*/,
        array('jquery')/*this script depends on jquery, so enqueue it automatically*/
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Doesn't fix all your problems but it's a step.

**2nd the html output**
your html output in `hello_world_html_page` will never display anywhere.
[`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) will retrieve a option from  the database, it won't execute a function.

```
function image() {
    hello_world_html_page()
}
add_shortcode('img', 'image');
```

This is better but stil wrong.
A short code can't `echo` or it will display properly you have to `return` it.

```
function hello_world_html_page() {
    return '<div id="demo-top-bar">
        <div id="slideshow">
            <div><img alt="TITLE" src="img0.jpg"></div>
            <div><img alt="TITLE"src="img1.jpg"></div>
            <div><img alt="TITLE"src="img2.jpg"></div>
            <div><img alt="TITLE"src="img3.jpg"></div>
            <div>
                Pretty cool eh? This slide is proof the content can be anything.
            </div>
        </div>';
}
```

**3rd the CSS**
You don't enqueue it anywhere.
If you fix the above 2 points you should be able to handle it:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style
As @swapnesh said there is a diffrence between `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: +1 @janw thanks, i follow your steps.. I checked scripts are coming fine.. but nothing is display on my page.. I am calling in my page using [img] shortcut..

Comment: I did tell you how to display the html.... replacing your `image` and `hello_world_html_page` with my suggestion should work

Comment: yes, great it is working... but image slider is not working properly.. I think i am very near to my goal...

Comment: @Learner I think janw described it beautifully what you need :)

Comment: @Learner did you get the CSS to work on your own? If so you "learned" a lot (bad joke)

Comment: @janw no i wrote code to attach my css file.. any ways thanks .. hahahah for your joke..